# Best way to sort a SystemVerilog associative array?

Tags: sorting, associative-array, system-verilog

I have an associative array and I need to process the items in that array in a certain order. What's the best way to do that?

Here is an example. Suppose I have an associative array of people's names and their ages:

```
int age[string];
age["bob"] = 32;
age["timmy"] = 4;
age["tyrian"] = 31;
```

I need to process this array from youngest person to oldest. Currently, I'm creating another array for indexing and sorting that.

```
  string sorted_age[$];

  // Is there a more efficient way to do this sort?
  foreach (age[i]) begin
    bit inserted = 0;
    foreach (sorted_age[j]) begin
      if (age[i] < age[sorted_age[j]]) begin
        sorted_age.insert(j, i);
        inserted = 1;
        break;
      end
    end
    if (!inserted) begin
      sorted_age.push_back(i);
    end
  end
```

Full example on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2_8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add one more queue then use the built in array methods. I haven't done a performance test (*which could be simulator dependent*), but it is fewer lines of code and easy to read.

```
  string sorted_age[$];
  int store_age [$];

  store_age = age.unique(); // find all unique ages (no duplicates)
  store_age.sort(); // sort by age
  foreach(store_age[i]) begin
    // multi entry puch_back
    sorted_age = {sorted_age, age.find_index with (item==store_age[i])};
  end
```

Full example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3EJ)

Comment: FYI, there is no guarantee that the array concatenation will be implemented as a multi-element push-back. If you are really concerned about the performance of this operation, you might to compare the concat with saving the result of find_index() into a temporary, and using a nested foreach loop to push_back each element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sort() with` functionality:

```
  // Create an aray of people's names
  string sorted_age[] = new [age.size()];
  int index = 0;
  foreach (age[i]) begin
    sorted_age[index++] = i;
  end

  // Sort the array
  sorted_age.sort() with (age[item]);
```

Full example on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3Mf